# Pass parameters into a mocked class' constructor in PHP/Mockery

Tags: php, mockery

This feels simple but the answer is eluding me behind internet pages and questions/answers, some of which I'm not confident enough to consider definitive.

My requirement is simple. I have a PHP class `ActionRequestService` which has two parameters. I would normally instantiate it:

`$actionRequestService = new ActionRequestService($param1, $param2);`

I'm mocking like:

`$actionRequestServiceMock = Mockery::mock(ActionRequestService::class);`

My question is, how do I get my parameters `$param1` and `$param2` into the class?

This is legacy code so cannot be changed and I need to achieve code coverage by writing more tests.

Comment: This https://docs.mockery.io/en/latest/reference/magic_methods.html suggests that maybe the `__construct` method is a "magic method" and therefore not suitable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass the parameters intended for the constructor as an array in the second parameter:

```
$actionRequestServiceMock = Mockery::mock(ActionRequestService::class, [
        $param1, $param2]);
```